# Moving a fixed width table inside a fixed width div

Tags: html, css

I have no control over the html in this project, so I need a css only solution unfortunately. The html is horrible, and it this wouldn't even be a problem if I could edit it. I have made a fiddle of where I am at at the moment.

I have a fixed width div, with a fixed width table inside it. They are the same width (500px in example) The table has an unset number of rows, generated in asp. I have floated the rows left so they appear in line (I know this is awful, but it was all I could do without editing the html) Each td is 100px. The heights and background colours added in the css are just to make it a bit clearer, they can be changed to whatever.

What I want to achieve is to get the td to start at the right hand side instead of the left. I have tried floating right instead of left, but this makes the links appear in reverse order which is undesirable.

The only solution I can come up with is to change the table width in css and float it to the right, which would be fine if the number of rows was a constant, but there could be some added to it or removed, which would leave it looking incorrect again.

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/TheWaxMann/YCbmg/4/)

Comment: which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: Without using JavaScript to re-write your HTML, you're stuck.

Comment: SupremeDud IE8 and above. Not too worried about the others. 
Diodeus that was what I feared.

Comment: @TheWaxMann Yeah you're a bit screwed then. If you were only concerned with moz / webkit, you could probably do it with flexbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were correct with your thought to  change the table width in css and float it to the right. I think I get what you want if I set the table width to 0px (it will expand to contain the tr's) in CSS, and float the table to the right.

Edit: nevermind. I was using Chrome and it worked there, but not in IE

Edit2: width:auto seems to make it work in IE, Chrome, and Firefox

Comment: Brilliant, the `width: auto` has sorted it. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I you have fixed width `td`s in your table, they should add up to 500px. In this case they add up to 400px. So you have to prepend one `tr` with auto width to your `table`.

Update: Hmm, this does not work since you have floating `tr`s instead of `td`s

Comment: I cannot change the html at all.